# How to acess GCS private Bucket file using Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-storage, gcp-load-balancer

I am trying to upload dist folder in GCS private bucket and trying to access javascript file using load balancer facing access denied error

can any one help how to access a file in private bucket other than https://storage.cloud.google.com/ this url any other way, without adding allUsers or allAuthenticatedUsers

I had tried configuring load balancer and given the backend bucket
and also added Network Admin, Storage Admin role

Comment: If it's private, you must expose a bearer Authorization token in the header. Your javascript client (the browser of the user) should add this header. Not sure it can.